# Admin Two-Factor Authentication Backup Code Forgotte

Tags: two-factor-authentication, nextcloud

I have a problem. Today I set up my nextCloud and wanted to activate a two-factor authentication directly.
I logged in as admin and activated the two-factor authentication. As I thought that you have to configure the two-factor authentication first, I logged out directly. Of course, I did not save the backup code.

Is there a way to get the backup code again? Or is there a way to bypass the two-factor authentication?

I still have full access to the server (via command line) but I cannot log into the account.

```
Two-factor authentication

Two-factor authentication is enforced but has not been configured for your account. Use one of your backup codes to log in, or contact your administrator for assistance.

Use backup code

Cancel login
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the NextCloud admin has forgotten the backup, but you have access to the terminal, there is a workaround. Simply create a new admin via OCC.

1. create a new admin account via client terminal

```sh
 sudo -u www-data php /var/www/nextcloud/occ user:add --display-name="<name>" --group="admin"  <name>
```

2. log in via NextCloud, an app has to be installed to confirm Two-Factor Authentication.
3. deactivate Admin Two-Factor Authentication
4. log in with the old admin account and set up Two-Factor Authentication again.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a new user etc, you can actually also use the `occ twofactorauth:disable` subcommand. The description says:

> twofactorauth:disable: Disable two-factor authentication for a user

The correct syntax is (correct the Nextcloud path if necessary):

```
sudo -u www-data /var/www/nextcloud/occ twofactorauth:disable USER_ID PROVIDER_ID
```

where the USER_ID is the username and the PROVIDER_ID the type of second factor, e.g., totp. In case it is unknown `sudo -u www-data php ./occ twofactorauth:state USER_ID` will be your friend.